# php get data from Jsonarray android volley

Tags: php, arrays, android-volley

I have read a lot of proposed solutions for reading data in php from volley JSON object and array. Before I start with a new solution I would like to explain my issue:

I send an ArrayList from android to php using and array:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList> params = new HashMap<String,ArrayList>();
params.put("campoid", resultjamkyList);
```

AndroidStudio Debugger shows the following:

```
resultjamkyList={ArrayList@5353} size = 9
                               0 = {Jamky@5429}
                                par = 4
                                delka = 330
                                .......
```

My php file

```
$kki = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$kk = $kki['campoid'];

var_dump($kk) shows Array(9) --> seems to able to read the data.

count($kk) returns 9, which is the right number.
```

But I am not able to get the array data. Tried a lot e.g.

```
for($i = 0;$i< count($kk);$i++){
echo = $kk[$i]["par"];}
```

but without a result. Did anybody have a similar issue?

---

UPDATE
I made a new approach with changing the parameters object.

```
HashMap<String,JSONArray> params -->instead of"ArrayList"
```

and then in the php file you can get the values with

```
echo $kki["campoid][i]["par]
```

Actually I have no idea why the ArrayList did'nt work, but there are many ways to reach the moon.

Comment: Do a [`var_dump`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.var-dump.php) on `$kki` and show us what data you have to work with.

Comment: first get the data and then try to decode.`$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: var_dump on $kki returns array(1)